# Disable button after clicked PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, button

How can I disable a button after it has been clicked. And let it remain disabled. I tried using `.prop('disabled', true);` although it disables the button, however when i refresh the page then button became clickable again. Also if I have a list of it, it would disable other button as well which I do not want. Is there anyway to do it?

```
<table>
<tr>
<td id="milestone_1"> 
</td>
<td id="percentage_1">
</td>
<td>
<form id="pay1">
<input type="hidden" class="id_hidden" name="id_hidden">
<input type="hidden" class="paid_hidden" name="paid_hidden">
<input type="hidden" class="budget_hidden" name="budget">
<input type="hidden" id="percent1" name="percent">
<input type="submit" name="pay1" value="Pay">
</form>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td id="milestone_2">
</td>
<td id="percentage_2">
</td>
<td>
<form id="pay2">
<input type="hidden" class="id_hidden" name="id_hidden">
<input type="hidden" class="paid_hidden" name="paid_hidden">
<input type="hidden" class="budget_hidden" name="budget">
<input type="hidden" id="percent2" name="percent">
<input type="submit" name="pay2" value="Pay">
</form>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td id="milestone_3">
</td>
<td id="percentage_3">
</td>
<td>
<form id="pay3">
<input type="hidden" class="id_hidden" name="id_hidden">
<input type="hidden" class="paid_hidden" name="paid_hidden">
<input type="hidden" class="budget_hidden" name="budget">
<input type="hidden" id="percent3" name="percent">
<input type="submit" name="pay3" value="Pay">
</form>
</td>
</tr>

</table>


$("#pay1").submit(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "pay.php",
        data: $("#pay1").serialize(),
        success: function(data){

            $("#add_success").html(data);
            $("#add_err").html("");

        }
    });
    return false
});
$("#pay2").submit(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "pay.php",
        data: $("#pay2").serialize(),
        success: function(data){

            $("#add_success").html(data);
            $("#add_err").html("");

        }
    });
    return false
});
$("#pay3").submit(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "pay.php",
        data: $("#pay3").serialize(),
        success: function(data){

            $("#add_success").html(data);
            $("#add_err").html("");

        }
    });
    return false
});
```

Comment: JS works only for current page elements. You should disable buttons on server side. So page loads with disabled items static. and effecting other buttons may because of same identifiers (id, name, class, ...) so jQuery finds more than one elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to you use cookie to keep user state or data.
simply you can use cookie in pure **javascript** by `document.cookie` object,

javascript create cookie sample code:

```
document.cookie="username=John Doe; expires=Thu, 18 Dec 2013 12:00:00 GMT; path=/";
```

read cookie:

```
var x = document.cookie;
```

also you can use [this](http://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/) jQuery plugin for handle that

cookie are very handy in PHP, so you can access cookie data by `$_COOKIE` global php variable.
Personally i recommend you to keep tag selector in javascript variable and disable them on **dom ready** for other later requests.

**UPDATE**

For more secure implementation you can use server-side solutions, for this case you can use PHP session to keep data for showing or not showing elements to user.

Comment: As is like a payment stuff, once that section is paid it will no longer be payable. So I dun think cookie will work in my situation here